# Top and bottom border will not disapear

Tags: html, css

This might seem like a newbie question, however after trying several hours, i have still not been able to remove a top and bottom border in a table.

Please visit http://dev.ateo.dk/om-ateo/ and check the table at the bottom of the page, with the two "Ateo" logos.

This has a top and bottom border. By doing "border-top: 0px" etc, and even using -webkit- and -moz-, nothing has worked. I am completely out of ideas of how to remove this top and bottom border using css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the `border-top` property from your `<td>` elements. Use the following CSS:

```
td {
    border-top: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the solution. A bit sad I had not discovered this - sometimes one just stare blank at the screen and see nothing even though its right there

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit td like this:

**CSS**(style.css)

```
td {
    border-top: 0 solid #EDEDED;
    padding: 6px 10px 6px 0;
}
```

Comment: @BenM: yes, but in the website the border has the value of 1px.. that's why i mentioned 0

Answer (score 0):

Remove border-top from your td element.

```
td { border-top: 1px solid #ededed; }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a  `border-top: 1px solid #ededed;` in your css file

[image]

Hope that will sort it for you.

Answer (score 0):

check and edit this style:
**http://dev.ateo.dk/wp-content/themes/ateo/style.css?vss=1404821487

now, comment out or edit the stylesheet to:

td { border-top: 0px solid #ededed; }

Regards !